# "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" when deploying online (using java)

Tags: google-app-engine

Why is below exception occuring ? Are there issues using google app engine with spring ?

My app works locally but when I deploy to online app engine I receive this error :

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

Here is my app engine log :

```
2012-02-15 13:13:16.357 / 500 128ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7
109.76.142.232 - - [15/Feb/2012:13:13:16 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7" "instantifier.appspot.com" ms=129 cpu_ms=280 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.007816 instance=00c61b117c0d70aee0093f560903362b39c9
I 2012-02-15 13:13:16.347
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
C 2012-02-15 13:13:16.354
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:422)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.
```

It seems you have wrong version of spring jars in classpath at runtime (which are not supported for the code you deployed).

Make sure you have correct version of jars.

Comment: What version of spring jars should I use with google app engine ?

Comment: You need to check your local GAE is same as online GAE or not, if not you need to refer the version and find out supporting jars from the documentation.

Comment: But my app was working up until two days ago. The src has changed but jar dependencies have always been the same.

Comment: Can you state what has changed in last 2 days?

Comment: This is a hobby project so will take at least 1 day to find whats changed, once I find whats changed I'll update the question

Comment: I've rolled back my project and its now working. I havent updated any jars so I don't what caused the inital issue.